# how do I get windows SCM to restart my service when it fails

Tags: windows, delphi, service

I have some windows services that i have written in delphi and they generally work very well, however on occasion i do get an exception thrown that can be considered fatal. When this happens the service is designed to stop.

My question is how do i exit the service in such a way that the SCM will automatically try to restart the service. (I have already set the recovery options for the service in the service manager)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685939%28VS.85%29.aspx) states

> A service is considered failed when it terminates without reporting a status of SERVICE_STOPPED to the service controller.

i have read this blog post [Using the Automatic Recovery Features of Windows Services](http://mdenomy.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/using-the-automatic-recovery-features-of-windows-services/) but i am not sure how to implement this in delphi.

i have allready tried the following

- Setting the ErrCode Property of the TService to a non zero value.
- Setting the stopped Parameter of the ServiceStop Event to false.
- Raising an exception in the servicestop event handler.

**EDIT 2013-08-06 added code example**

***Code Now Updated to show working example***

Here is the code im using,

```
procedure TTestService.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin

  while not (Terminated or FFatalError) do
  begin
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(False);
    ReportStatus;
    Sleep(100);
  end;

  if FFatalError then
   Halt(1);

end;
```

FFatalError is a private boolean field on the TTestService class and is initialized to false on startup, it is only set to true if the worker thread (started in the TTestService.ServiceStart event) terminates with a fatal exception.

here is the OnTerminate event handler for the worker thread.

```
procedure TTestService.ThdTerm(Sender: Tobject);
var
  E : Exception;
  Thread : TThread;
begin
  Thread := TThread(Sender);

  if (Thread.FatalException <> nil) then
  begin
    E := Exception(Thread.FatalException);
    GetExcCallStack(E);

    EventLog.LogError(Thread.ClassName + ': ID:'+ IntToStr(Thread.ThreadID) +
      ' Stopped Unexpectedly!, '+ NEWLINE + E.ClassName +': ' + E.Message);
    FFatalError := True;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Did you try calling `ExitProcess`?

Comment: "When this happens the service is designed to stop." That could be the problem. You might have to choose between handling the exception or letting it genuinely fail. Perhaps if you post the code that "is designed to stop" the service, we might be able to see more clearly.

Comment: Just terminate service process via Task Manager. If SCM restart config for your service is correct, service will be restarted.

Comment: @Alexandr MikeT is looking for a programmatic way to do it

Comment: I'd rather try to eliminate the exception if possible. It's never a good practice to let the service fail.

Comment: @MikeT try `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess, 0);`

Comment: @Alexandr Why would you recommend `TerminateProcess` rather than `ExitProcess`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Because ExitProcess expects the correct completion of the process. TS need emulate to fatal error situation. For this purpose, it's better to use a `TerminateProcess` or even better `halt` command.

Comment: @Alexandr That makes no sense to me. "ExitProcess expects the correct completion of the process" means nothing. What do you think happens when you call `Halt`? See if you can guess which Windows API function is called.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan, I tried to click into System.Halt but I can't find its implementation in System.pas. Is there a way to know as opposed to guess?

Comment: @Sam Build with debug dcus and step into the function. It's an intrinsic. And of course it ends with a call to ExitProcess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SCM will restart your service if it fails. But all the normal termination modes from a Delphi service do not count as *failure*. If you could raise an exception from the main service thread that was unhandled, then that would count as a failure.

However, I think the simplest way for you to force a process termination that is treated as a failure is to call `ExitProcess`. You could equally well call the Delphi RTL function `Halt` which will ultimately call `ExitProcess`. However, since your process is probably in a bad state I'd be inclined to go straight to `ExitProcess`.

As has already been commented, avoiding the exception in the first place would be the ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks for your help i have got this working now and have updated the code in the question to show my solution